# NG8001 Error at Component Header to app in angular web

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, visual-studio

I create a small angular web and I create Header dir with commandlline `ng g c Header`
[image]and I write a small sympil paragraph ** in header.component.html**

```
<p>header works!</p>
```

[image]
and this the code in **header.component.ts **

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrl: './header.component.scss'
})
export class HeaderComponent {

}
```

[image]
and in **app.component.html**
`<app-header></app-header>`
and in **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'MyFirstProjectDeveloperAkademie1Test';
}
```

and when I run with command line **ng serve** I get this error

[image]

somebody can help ,
this is the error
[image]

Comment: Add `HeaderComponent` to `AppComponent` imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HeaderComponent` needs to be imported by the consumer (`AppComponent`) as you are utilizing standalone components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, HeaderComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'MyFirstProjectDeveloperAkademie1Test';
}
```

Comment: thank you , it is run without error now.